# Pretty urls with php and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, pretty-urls

Please take it easy on me as this is a completely new world on my part.

So I have built and Little cms and using GET to control the pageID or page permalink in the url.I have the script working fine when only passing 1 variable through the query string

For example my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

I can then call my pages by id or permalink controlled in my index file. One thing I am failing to figure out is how to include a parent permalink in the url as well when a child page is called.

Another example. If I call a page that is a child of a parent:

```
http://site.com/index.php?p=post-title
```

if post-title is a child of parent-title; How can I use the url

```
http://site.com/parent-title/post-title?
```

Comment: Are you talking about something like when someone requests `http://site.com/parent-title/post-title`, the request gets rewritten to your index.php controller like `/index.php?p=post-title&parent=parent-title`?

Comment: I have thought of that but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically include the parent-title when only calling the post-title

I am sure there is a way but mod_rewrites are all but english to me.
But to answer your question. Yes I was like it to what you suggested but still keep clean urls

Comment: So you mean like: `/index.php?p=parent-title/post-title`?

Comment: Well it more seems like you first suggestion `/index.php?p=post-title&parent=parent-title` but not only call the child page and automatically include the parent page in the url as well. Hope that makes since

Comment: When someone requests `http://site.com/parent-title/post-title`, what do you want the URI to look like?

Comment: exactly that `http://site.com/parent-title/post-title`.. I guess I may be answering my own question with your help..

I am wanting `http://site.com/index.php?p=post-title` to go to `http://site.com/parent-title/post-title`
From just posting here I am going to have to do some magic with PHP in the Index page to grab the parent of the requested post and somehow generate the pretty url the way you have suggested
Answer and I will give the plus

Answer (score 0):

First, we can place all of our code in Apache .htaccess files. This could look something like this:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

Let’s start at the top and work our way down to better understand what is going on here. The first line sets the environment up to follow symbolic links using the Options directive. This may or may not be necessary, but some web hosts use symlinks (similar to alias in MacOSX or shortcuts is Windows) for common HTTP request errors and these are usually symlinked files, or at least this is how I understand the reasoning. Next we tell Apache we are going to use the Rewrite Engine. The next two lines are very, very important it restricts rewriting URLs only to paths that do not actually exists. This prevents the rules below from matching example.com/images/logo.png for example. The first prevents existing directories with the !-d flag and the second with !-f means ignore existing files.
The next three lines are the actual URL rewriting commands. Each line creates a rule that tries to match a regular expressions pattern against the incoming URL